# как делать create в контроллере в ручную.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Привет, помогите пожалуйста разобраться как это сделать и как это делать правильно. Я делаю киносайт. использую гем который парсит кинопоиск. Задумка создания фильма грубо говоря: в форме есть одно поле ввода - это название фильма. Дальше я отправляю форму и по этому названию парсер ищет сам фильм на кинопоиске. Оттуда я беру описания, актёров, режисёров и т.д. и записываю всё в свою базу. Как мне правильно записать эти значения?

```
def create
@movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @movie.save и т.д.

def movie_params
 search = KpApi::FilmSearch.new(params.require(:movie).permit(:title))
 params = {movie: {title: '#{search.name_ru}', role: '#{search.peoples.to_s}', year: '#{search.year.to_s}'}}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно использовать movie_params для этого, вы же из формы получаете только title. Вызываете парсер и на основании его результатов создаёте фильм, проверяете валидность, решаете, что делать дальше

```
def create
  kp_movie = KpApi::FilmSearch.new(params[:movie][:title])
  # здесь надо как-то обработать ситуацию, когда фильм не был найден на КП
  @movie = Movie.new(title: kp_movie.name_ru, role: kp_movie.peoples.to_s, year: kp_movie.year.to_s)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @movie.save 
      ...
end
```